# getstream.io - How to get the total of aggregated activities on Notification feeds

Tags: python, getstream-io

When using Notification feed shouldn't the **activity_count** and **actor_count** vars return the total of aggregated activities? A note on the Aggregated feed's docs says *"...The actor and object count do increase past 15"*, but it does not seem the case for Notification counts (Also, this note is not present on Notification feed's docs).

As test I'm inserting 20 activities for some notification group (for example: a "like" notification activity, each one with a different actor). When reading the feed I'm getting the last 15 activities on **results.activities** attribute (what it's ok), but the **activity_count** and **actor_count** attributes keep returning 15 instead of 20.

Am I doing something wrong or it's the right behavior for these attributes? Is there another way to get the total of aggregated activities?

My aggregation format is:

```
{% if verb.infinitive == 'like' or verb.infinitive == 'following' %}
    {{ object }}
{% else %}
    {{ id }}
{% endif %}
```

I'm using the Python client to access the API.

Comment: Hey Ricardo, Nick here from Stream. We're actively looking into the issue and should have a response to you in the next 24-48 hours. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Hi there, I wanted to reach out to let you know that I had a moment to chat with the team. Unfortunately, the docs were out of date. We're resolving the issue now and the documentation will be updated in the next release. Have a great day!

Comment: Hi Nick, may you say in advance what is the correct behavior? Is it limited to 15 or there is another way to get the total activities?

Comment: The new docs have been updated to "Note: Each activity group inside an aggregated feed contains the 15 most recent activities. If you add more than 15 activities to one group, older activities will no longer be visible. Enterprise customers can contact support to increase this limit." – I hope this helps. Thanks!